Understanding Gemini API documentation
I am trying to understand Gemini API for my Flutter project. However, in the documentation, I do not understand this "In the VS Code Extension Development Host window, write in a code comment describing the user interface component you want to generate".
In VS Code Extension Development window, I could not find any option to write "code comment". You can check this documentation Gemini API documentation
Anybody can help me understand it? Thanks.

What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to call the Gemini API? Or do you want to use Gemini CodeAssist that generate code based on your context (your comment including)? Side note: At Google, everything is Gemini and it's difficult to understand clearly what you are using! Add as many details as you can!

@guillaumeblaquiere I am learning it to integrate into Flutter. However in the documentation "Modify existing command", I do not understand "In the VS Code Extension Development Host window, select a code comment in the editor window describing the button style you want, for example:..". How do you select code comment in the editor window?

If you use gemini code assist, in your IDE, you can select your code and ask the Gemini chat panel to perform things. But it's not flutter only, it works with many languages. And it's not about API also.

In order to use the flutter code generation feature with the instruction you quoted, you need to install the flutter theme agent first. Then, you can add a comment and use the agent command to execute the code generation action. which in turn calls the gemini API.

The Flutter tutorial might be the best way to get started with the Gemini API in your app. The tutorial you're looking at is for creating a code generator, which might be a bit more advanced if you don't know the basics yet.

@RosárioPereiraFernandes I understand now. You need to open your project in the host window and then you can use Gemini API in your project.
